# Does MySQL timestamp take current server time or user?

Tags: mysql, timestamp

Does MySQL timestamp take current server time or User,s computer time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the current time zone for each connection is the server's time

Answer (score 0):

It takes whatever you give it. If you are using now() when doing an insert, then it's going to use the server's time.